# 'tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist' has no attribute 'read_data_sets'

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist as input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST-data", one_hot=True)
```

**Error message:**

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist' has no
> attribute 'read_data_sets'

Comment: Follow [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data)

Answer (score 0):

As above error shows there is no attribute 'read_data_sets' in `'tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist'` module. However you can access mnist dataset in following two ways:

1.Loads the mnist dataset

```
import tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist as input_data

mnist = input_data.load_data("MNIST-data")
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist
```

OR directly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

2.To plug TensorFlow Datasets (TFDS) into a Keras model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load('mnist',
                                         split=['train', 'test'],
                                         shuffle_files=True,
                                         as_supervised=True,
                                         with_info=True,)
```